# error:- main.cpp:11:19: error: no matching function for call in the push_back line

Tags: c++, vector

I have been trying to execute this code, and I am getting an error:

```
main.cpp:11:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)’
   v.push_back(s[2]);
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s="abc";
    vector<string>v;
    v.push_back(s[2]);
    cout<<v[0];
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want this code to do? You have a vector of strings and you are trying to push a single character to it. This doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You forgot to tell us what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: it was just a smaller chunk of code to my program which i was trying to run, i have a condition where i have to store some characters as well as a string in a vector and this was not accepting a character as you specified, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Indexing into a string like this:

```
s[2]
```

gives you a `char`, and there's no overload of `push_back` for `vector<string>` that takes a `char`.

Instead, you can use the initializer list constructor for `string` like this, to pass a string containing a single character:

```
v.push_back( { s[2] } );
```

Answer (score 1):

`s[2]` is a character (type `char`), so it cannot be inserted to vectors that accept `string`.

The [constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
basic_string( size_type count,
              CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

is useful to create strings from one character.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s="abc";
    vector<string>v;
    v.push_back(std::string(1, s[2]));
    cout<<v[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push a single `char` into a `std::vector` of `std::string` elements.  `std::string` does not have a constructor that takes only a single `char` as input (but it does have an `operator=` that does).

So, you will have to either:

- Change the `std::vector` to hold `char` elements instead of `std::string` elements:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "abc";
    vector<char> v;
    v.push_back(s[2]);
    cout << v[0];
   
    return 0;
}
```

- Change how you are constructing the `std::string` objects that you are pushing into the `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "abc";
    vector<string> v;

    v.push_back(string(1, s[2]));
    //
    // or:
    // v.push_back(string(&s[2], 1));
    //
    // or:
    // string tmp;
    // tmp = s[2];
    // v.push_back(tmp);

    cout << v[0];
   
    return 0;
}
```